# select smalldatetime between two smalldatetimes in another table

Tags: sql, date, smalldatetime

i need to select ( small date time) from  ( date ) user will enters

like

table have

```
2013-07-05 09:12:00
2014-07-03 10:12:00
2014-07-04 13:32:00
2014-07-08 14:30:00
2014-07-06 08:27:00
```

named times

when user enter date from calender it convert to 2014-07-06 00:00:00 and save in another table named user_time

so i need when user enter date select only day that the user type !!!!

???

i tired

```
SELECT  day.time
FROM            day  INNER JOIN
                         user ON day.time >= user.time
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `BETWEEN` clause and the `DateAdd()` function to get just one day.  Try this query:

```
SELECT day.time
FROM day  INNER JOIN [user]
     ON day.time BETWEEN [user].time AND DateAdd(d, 1, [user].time)
```